# How to get element by javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I select the element by its function?

for example

**HTML**

```
<button id="saveButton" onClick="javascript:fnSave(this)>
    Save
</button>
```

then **javascript**

```
function fnSave(element){

console.log($(element).attr('id'));

}
```

clicking the button will result : `saveButton`

Comment: did you try it??? what happened?

Comment: you forgot to close the onClick `"`

Comment: oh... it worked.. i just forgot the quotes >.< my bad

Comment: @rjmcb you should use a syntax highlighter, these errors are easily spotable with them. I recommend you Notepad++, with a simple click it points you where the brackets/quotes/parenthesis/etc are opened/closed among with other awesome features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with using the currentTarget - like this:

```
save = function(object){
    console.log($(object).attr('id'));
}
```

And, you would call this from your HTML like you mentioned - just including the quote:

```
<button id="saveButton" onClick="save(this)">Save</button>
```

Comment: That will probably assign `undefined` to variable. Also OP is asking how to get the element, not the `id`

Comment: Actually, I was going off of his code. From what I see here, current target will work just fine. It depends on how the function is called. When it is called like the OP showed, it will send in a event object: http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Comment: Just looked at it again. Thank you, I think I was getting the two methods of calling mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

To get the element you can do what you just did, add `onClick='fnSave(this)'` to the button, and on the function:

```
function fnSave(element){
    //the element is in 'element'
}
```

But I see you are using jQuery, so you can remove the `onClick` and use this:

```
$("#saveButton").click(function(event){
   var element = $(this);//the element is in 'element'
});
```

**Note:** if you are going to use this for multiple different buttons, it would be wise to select them by a clasName instead, or use the first function.
*edited*